# TypeError: expressValidator is not a function

Tags: node.js

Estou tendo dificuldade para resolver a questão abaixo onde aparece a mensagem 
**"TypeError: expressValidator is not a function"**

```js
var express = require('express');
var consign = require('consign');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './app/views');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(expressValidator());

consign()
    .include('app/routes')
    .then('config/dbConnection.js')
    .then('app/models')
    .into(app);

module.exports = app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/)

Na hora em que voce instancia o express, voce tem que instanciar da seguinte maneira:

```js
// ...rest of the initial code omitted for simplicity.
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

app.post('/user', [
  // username must be an email
  check('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], (req, res) => {
  // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }).then(user => res.json(user));
});
```

Testei aqui da seguinte forma e funcionou:

`var { check, expressValidator } = require('express-validator');
app.use(check)`

Comment: Me desculpe, eu não tinha lido a documentação do validator, irei alterar a resposta.

Comment: Opa amigo, agora deu certo?

Comment: Deu certo @Claudio H. Yoshii